# Using command substitution in find -exec

Tags: bash, shell

How can I use command substitution in `find … -exec …` to avoid using `xargs` in the following command?

```sh
find -L -- /path/to/directory -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec dirname '{}' \; | xargs basename -a
```

I tried the following using command substitution, but it output `.` for each result instead of the desired output:

```sh
find -L -- /path/to/directory -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec basename "$(dirname '{}')" \;
```

Comment: What are you trying to return?

Comment: The first command works fine (except for the space bug noted in an answer below).  I'm trying to return the names of the parent directories (not the full path, but rather just the last element of the path) of the directories that match `find -L -- /path/to/directory -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d`

Answer (score 2):

Your first command will return strange results if a path contains whitespace.

Use a small shell script:

```
find -L -- . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec sh -c 'basename "$(dirname "{}")"' \;
```

Alternative syntax to pass one path argument to the script:

```
find -L -- . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec sh -c 'basename "$(dirname "$1")"' sh {} \;
```

Or pass as many arguments to the script as possible:

```
find -L -- . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec sh -c '
  for path do
    basename "$(dirname "$path")"
  done
' sh {} +
```

With GNU utilities it's possible to output NUL-terminated strings with `dirname` passed to `xargs -0`. The `basename` command is not run if there are no arguments (`-r`):

```
find -L -- . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec dirname -z {} + | xargs -r0 basename -a
```

Comment: How can I fix my original `xargs` command to properly handle paths that contain whitespace?  I tried using `-print0` for `find` & `-0` for `xargs`, but it didn't work

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  The version of `dirname` included with macOS doesn't accept `-z`, `--zero`, or any other options.  `xargs` also doesn't support `-d`, just `-0`.  The limitations of the macOS versions of core utilities can be frustrating.